# Bootstrap Date Range Picker on Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, daterangepicker

I added the Bootstrap Date Range Picker in my Rails 4 app and I got a problem.

**Situation:**

That's how my code looks atm:

```
// Script
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            language: "de-DE"
    });
    $('.daterange').daterangepicker({
            'startDate': false,
            'endDate': false,
            'minDate': setDate(),
            'autoApply': true,
            "opens": "center",
            "locale": {
                "format": "DD.MM.YYYY",
                "separator": " - ",
                "daysOfWeek": ["So","Mo","Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
                "monthNames": ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
                "firstDay": 1
            }
        },
        function(start, end, label) {
            $("#booking_start_date").val(start.format("DD.MM.YYYY"));
            $("#booking_end_date").val(end.format("DD.MM.YYYY"));

    });

//View
<%= text_field_tag 'date', nil, class: 'form-control daterange' %>
<%= f.input :start_date, as: :hidden %>
<%= f.input :end_date, as: :hidden %>
```

So what it is supposed to do is call the daterangepicker on the `text_field` and pass the chosen value to the hidden fields where the start and end dates are passed to the controller for saving.

**Problem:**

The problem is that when I load the page there is always the same value inside of the `text_field` and it's always the current date (e.g. today: 29.10.2015 - 29.10.2015). Obviously the field should be empty for creating a new objekt and should show the current value of the attribute for editing an existing object. So what I tried is adding some jquery which is not really doing anything atm.

**Solution (not working):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var start = $("#booking_start_date").val();
    var end = $("#booking_end_date").val();
    if (start != '' && end != '') {
        $('.daterange').val(start + "-" + end);
    } else {
        $('.daterange').val("");
    }
});
```

So I thought if I catch the values from the hidden fields and put them together and pass the resulting string to the `text_field` it should work. And if there are no values in the hidden fields it should show an empty string. But as said it's not doing anything. If I test my function with some alerts is gives me the right values back. But the `text_field` is still showing the same thing as without the new function.

So any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and my first solution was to "cheat" a little; since daterangepicker will pick up the initial value from the form input, I filled it in server-side;

```
%input.daterange{type: "text", name: "date_range_picker_app_per", value: "#{app_per.start_on} - #{app_per.end_on}"}
```

The trick here is to ensure that your date formats are aligned; that is, daterangepicker needs to know what format Rails will put into that field. Your use of the locale option was what I used to make daterangepicker understand Rails's default date format.

This approach did expose a problem, though: what if start_on and end_on aren't set? To cover that case, I moved the generation of the range initial value to a helper method:

```
def range_initial_value(thingy)
  if thingy.start_on.present?
    "#{thingy.start_on} - #{thingy.end_on}"
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

Then I call the helper method in the HAML above. That satisfies daterangepicker since it won't receive " - " as an initial value.

Mine works now, and also works with an arbitrary number of date range pickers, so I'm happy.